# remove specific lines of file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have to file suppost 1.txt and 2.txt
1.txt has a number in each line indicate the itemID. for example

```
43
345
65
```

the second file is csv and has the following pattern
userID,itemID,time

I want to remove from second file all lines which their itemID is in the first file
for this purpose I do the following

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r var 
do
 paste -sd '|' | xargs -I{} grep -v -E {} 2.txt
done < "1.txt"
```

I read the first file and create a regular expression, but don't know the argument of egrep to get the second filed(itemID)

Comment: Can you show some sample values for file2 i.e. csv file?

Comment: post a fragment of your `2.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk

```
awk -F "," 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=1;next} a[$2]!=1{print}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

- `a[$0] = 1` records item id that exists in 1.txt into an array `a`
- `a[$2] != 1` prints out lines from 2.txt that does not have the item id in array `a`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to add commas to the beginning and end of each id in 1.txt, then just use `grep` to filter out the resulting strings:

```
sed 's/^\|$/,/g' 1.txt | grep -vFf- 2.txt
```

- `-F` interprets the patterns as fixed strings, i.e. not regular expressions
- `-f` tells grep to read the patterns from the given file, in this case `-`, i.e. standard input